# Little exercise on smooth funcions

Tags: real-analysis

"Let $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$, then there exists $f_1,f_2\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^N)$ positive such that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^N$, $f(x)=f_1(x)-f_2(x)$."

Comment: I tried using bump functions, with no success so far.

Comment: the smooth functions with domain $\mathbb{R}^N$

Comment: and image in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @RSerrao: Your comments are not really useful and the question is clear. You are probably mistaking $N$ (a natural number) for $\Bbb N$ (the set of natural numbers).

Comment: @AlexM. gosh, you are probably right. I may have confused the typesetting. either way, the exercise was solvable even without me being able to understand what that $N$ was. Thanks for your polite critique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try considering

$$f_1(x) = f(x)^2 + f(x) + 1$$

And

$$f_2(x) = f(x)^2 + 1$$